# Photoshop: Make canvas stay present

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two monitors. When I click away on the monitor that doesn't have Photoshop, the canvas goes blank like this. If I click again everything appears back normally. Is there a way to disable to disappearing action though?

This also happens when I'm working on a layer, it hides the other layers. It'd be great if there was a way to disable that hiding part.

[image]

Comment: This is a technical issue, often due to the version of the OS you may be running. Sorry, it's off topic here. You might want to ask Adobe.

Comment: At a guess you have "Displays have separate Spaces" switched on in Mission Control prefs, also you may be running Ps in fullscreen. neither of those are conducive to a good dual display setup.